# flutter setState function does not work in the onChange of my checkbox

Tags: json, flutter, setstate

help me please.
I would like to make an quiz app. I made a Question function. Now I can't use the setState function to detect if the checkbox is checked or not.
I would like to use the boleen of my Map proposition to change the state of the checkbox if it is checked or not.
I have an error like

***The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'Question'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.dartundefined_method***

An in the console i have this error

*═══════════Exception caught by gesture ════════

Stack Overflow*

This is what my code looks like

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question {
  final int? id;
  final String? question;
  final Map<String, bool> proposition;
  final String? reponse;
  final String? commentaire;

  Question({
    this.id,
    this.question,
    this.commentaire,
    required this.proposition,
    this.reponse,
  });
  Widget lister() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("$question"),
        for (var i in proposition.keys)
          // bool val=this.proposition.values;
          Row(children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: proposition.values,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
//here the setState is underlined in red. and does not work
                setState(() {
                  value = value!;
                });
              },
              
            ),
            Text(i),
          ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

An d I use this class in this dart file

```
import 'package:anassa2/qcm/questions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:anassa2/home/custom_form.dart';

class MonQcm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MonQcm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MonQcm> createState() => _MonQcmState();
}

class _MonQcmState extends State<MonQcm> {
  CostumForm vrai = CostumForm(
    placeholder: "cool",
    title: "trxy",
  );
  Question question1 = Question(
    id: 1,
    question: "comment s'appel le president du faso",
    proposition: {"rock": false, "bala": false, "Damiba": false},
    reponse: "rock",
    commentaire: "Les commentaires c'est par la",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          question1.lister(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: setState method only works with Stateful Widgets, `Question` is a class not a widget,  you might want to understand flutter basics. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Answer (score 0):

`setState` works in `StatefulWidget` but not in default class

class `Question` must be `StatefulWidget` use `class Question extends StatefulWidget {..`

or call callback function in `MonQcm` class

Comment: ok. thank you very much. I would retry

Comment: don't reminder change widget call here from
`children: [
          question1.lister(),
        ],`
to 
`children: [
          Question(
  id: ..,
  question: ..,
  proposition: ..,
  reponse: ..,
  commentaire: ..,
),
        ],`